# Typescript csv-parse

Tags: csv, typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to parse a csv file with typescript which I am totally new to. I cannot get the parser working with the correct typings.

Without typings everything is easy:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var parse = require('csv-parse');

var parser = parse({delimiter: ';'}, function(err, data){
  console.log(data);
});

fs.createReadStream(__dirname+'/fs_read.csv').pipe(parser);
```

But when it comes to typescript I get errors, I installed the typings [from dt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nashika/typed-csv-parse/b300d8674f93cfd70a02e5c45354d980a7179a2e/index.d.ts) :

```
import * as csvParse from 'csv-parse';
import fs = require('fs');
var myParser:csvParse.CsvParser = csvParse({delimiter: ','}, function(data, err) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

I get the error

```
Type 'void | CsvParser' is not assignable to type 'CsvParser'.
```

Can anyone give me a hint or used csv-parse with typescript before and share their code?

Comment: what are you trying to do here `csvParse({delimiter: ','}, function(data, err)....`?

Comment: I want myparser to be of Type csv Parser tat implements writablestream for the last line of Code. I also tried `class myparser implements csvParse.CsvParser` But then I could not get the parsed data

Comment: Does this work `new csvParse.CsvParse({delimiter: ','}, function(data, err)....`

Comment: `Only a void function can be called with the 'new' keyword`

Comment: For anyone who is copying code from OP's question, replace `parse` in line 3 with `parse.parse`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### 1. Let typescript do the work for you

Do not explain which type you want as a result of method `csvParse`:

```js
var myParser = csvParse({delimiter: ','}, function(data, err) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

### 2. Use the original cast operator `<>`

```js
var myParser:csvParse.CsvParser = <csvParse.CsvParser> csvParse({delimiter: ','}, function(data, err) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

> Note: This only work with `.ts` files. In `.jsx` files you will see error "Expected corresponding JSX closing tag for ..."

### 3. Use the new operator `as`

```js
var myParser:csvParse.CsvParser = csvParse({delimiter: ','}, function(data, err) {
  console.log(data);
}) as csvParse.CsvParser;
```

Answer (score 12):

This is just a simple casting issue, all your code is right, its just TS needs help knowing what is being returned from CsvParse. If you take a look at the definition file, its return signature is `void|parse.CsvParser`.
So to tell TS that it is actually a CsvParser (and not void) just cast it:

```
var myParser:csvParse.CsvParser = csvParse({delimiter: ','}, function(data, err) {
    console.log(data);
}) as csvParse.CsvParser;
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running into a different problem and had to change the index.d.ts in @types/csv-parse from:

```
export = parse;
```

to:

```
export default parse;
```

This allowed me to access the parse function and pass it to the fs stream properly.